# Random select array with remove items (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random

I am trying to find a way to get values from an array of random way without repeating them, I found the following solution:

```js
var letters = ["A", "B", "C"];
var getRandom = (function(array) {
  var notGivenItems = array.map(function(el) {
    return el;
  });
  var getIndex = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * notGivenItems.length);
  };

  return function() {
    if (notGivenItems.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    return notGivenItems.splice(getIndex(), 1)[0];
  };
})(letters);

console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
console.log(getRandom());
```

If I print the `console.log()` 4 times, at last, the array appears as `undefined`, and that's precisely what I need. However, I need `(function () {...` don't be fired automatically, because the value that comes via `AJAX`. So, should be something like:

```js
function selec() {

  var getRandom = (function(array) {
    var notGivenItems = array.map(function(el) {
      return el;
    });
    var getIndex = function() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * notGivenItems.length);
    };

    return function() {
      if (notGivenItems.length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      return notGivenItems.splice(getIndex(), 1)[0];
    };
  })(letters);

  return getRandom();
}

console.log(selec());
```

But then, the function continues printing values continuously, without return `undefined`.

Comment: Are you declaring `letters` inside or outside `selec()`?

Comment: Out, because if it is inside, when run `select()` again, `letters` back to  original format.

Comment: Every time you call `selec()` you re-initialize `array` from `letters`.

Comment: `because the value that comes via AJAX`... which value? `letters`? Also, what do you exactly expect when you call `console.log(selec());`?

Comment: what do you mean saying "comes via AJAX" ? your first function should work the same

Comment: Sorry, AJAX is used on another occasion. The same is in the comment of the response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have understood your problem.. if yes, was really easy. Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/bmpq4jmb/)**

```js
var letters = ["A", "B", "C"];

function getRandom(array){
  var notGivenItems = array.map(function(el){
    return el;
  });
  var getIndex=function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * notGivenItems.length)
  };
  if (notGivenItems.length === 0)
    return;
  return array.splice(getIndex(), 1)[0];
}

console.log(getRandom(letters));
console.log(getRandom(letters));
console.log(getRandom(letters));
console.log(getRandom(letters));
```

Comment: I often say that if a problem is too hard, it's because you're doing it the wrong way. It's really simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that every time you call `selec()`, it is re-creating the `getRandom` function.

What you need to do is define `getRandom` outside of the `selec()` function scope.

You can do it at the same level:

```
var getRandom = (function(array) { ... })(letters);
var selec = function() { return getRandom; };
```

*or* you can create a closure to protect `getRandom` from naming conflicts:

```
var selec = (function() {
    var getRandom = (function(array) { ... })(letters);
    return function() { return getRandom; };
})();
```

Comment: This worked very well. Just changed `return getRandom;` to `return getRandom ();`
However, for my scenario where be worked with AJAX as follows:
`$ .AJAX ({
type: ' GET ',
URL: ' json ', questions.
datatype: ' json ',
success: function (data) {
var arr = [];
for (var index in data) {
arr. push (index ++);
}
window.ind = arr;
}
})`
When overriding the `letters` by `window.ind`, the array becomes `undefined`.
Thanks again!